# How to install GParted?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I want to install the software : "GParted". But, I couldn't find it!

1. Where can I find it?
2. How can I install GParted?

Answer (score 0):

Please first check whether an answer is available by searching through Google before raising it as a question here.

To install gparted

Open a terminal using `super+T or Win+T` or from the applications menu.

First run

```
 sudo apt update
```

then

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

Similarly to remove run,

```
sudo apt remove gparted
sudo apt autoremove
```